# Can you develop an econometrics model for stress test purpose only focusing on 2008-2009 data?

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I have become aware that a group at a large corporation is developing an econometrics model to forecast sales of their product.  They are using this model solely to estimate sales in specified stress test economic scenarios where they are given what the economic environment will be like, including real GDP contraction, rising unemployment rate, etc... out to 2016.  Because of the nature of those scenarios, they think the most proper way to construct this model is to focus solely on the 2008-2009 period capturing the main period of the recent financial crisis.  They have monthly data, so that gives them 24 monthly data points.  Given that GDP's frequency is really quarterly, on this one variable it gives them only 8 true datapoints.  But, they extrapolate it into 24 month observations.

For the record, if they chose to, they have good internal data going back to 2001 and up to the current period.  But, as mentioned they decided to focus instead solely on the 2008-2009 period.

I will also answer this question as I have built many such econometrics models.  And, I invite others to debate and rebutt my answer... and to post your own better answer.

Comment: Is it appropriate to focus solely on the 2008-2009 period (learning sample of the model) to develop an econometrics model earmarked for estimating what would happen in adverse economic scenarios? I gather I am simply repeating my question. As is, I think it is clear enough.

Comment: You can answer it in a precise way.  The answer is either Yes, No, or it depends.  The key is to support one's answer most rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

The points you are making are valid, but there are also arguments that if not counter to yours, they create a dilemma:

When trying to estimate and forecast extreme cases, incorporating information from "normal times" may "average" your predictor, which would then be more reliable to estimate long-term trends rather than short-term (and severe) fluctuations. Models that describe well *both* these aspects are still not available, because we do not yet understand well how "normal times" breed their own crises (in "normal times" I include the concept of a business cycle - a crisis is something much more severe).

One could build *three* models: one based just on "crisis data", one based on only "normal times" data, and one based on both data. Comparing the *three* in terms of their forecasts would be very valuable. Also one could  implement "model-averaging" on the two "pure" models and compare its forecasts with the "both kind of data" model forecasts.

Since they are a large corporation and only in it for the money, this multiplication of resources allocation to estimate their sales can be justified -and financed.

Comment: The learning sample would not include just "normal times."  It would also include the 2008-2009 crisis.  By grabing the entire data set from 2001 to present, this corporation could develop a more robust econometrics model that would cover the entire range of economic scenarios.  I guess that is equivalent to your solution of building a model "based on both data."  I am not sure of the merit of building two extra models one for normal economic environment and a separate one for crisis economic environment.  Actually, I have never heard of any economists doing it that way.

Comment: ...And this is because we didn't have to deal with, explain and forecast, an economic crisis like the recent one.

Comment: A learning sample from 2001 to 2013 would fully capture the 2008-2009 period.

Comment: I would like to see that, _and_ see the model forecasting accurately out-of-sample.

Comment: The out-of-sample issue is magnified when you ignore 80% of the data.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that my answer does NOT say "ignore the normal times data because you try to forecast extreme times" - on the contrary, in face of being "between a rock and a hard place", it proposes a tentative empirical approach that will tell us first and foremost _if_ (and how much) differently the model behaves under different sets of data. The next step would totally depend on the results from this first phase.

Comment: Sorry, I gather I misinterpreted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting and topical issue in risk modelling. In my experience, risk models for credit which are developed on shorter periods of data tend to produce unstable coefficients - cross validation and/or out-of-time testing for model performance have usually shown this to be the case.

For stress testing of credit risk models, we are concerned with estimating probability of default (PD, probability of customer not repaying a loan) and loss given default (LGD, proportion of loan lost in event of default) during downturn macroeconomic conditions.

In terms of regulatory perspectives for stress testing, the [Basel Committee on Banking Supervision (BCBS)](http://www.bis.org/bcbs/about.htm), which can be considered the central bank of central banks, indicates a minimum of 5 to 7 years of data (dependent on model and portfolio type) for model development, unless strong evidence is shown that more recent data is more predictive. Banking regulators typically adhere to these time periods as part of Basel II and III standards for calculating regulatory capital.

Additionally, the time period of 2008 to 2009 would seem to be somewhat short as the financial crisis has persisted for a longer period in some countries, e.g. UK where macro economic conditions worsened in 2007. It could be argued that the crisis is still ongoing in some parts of the world.

Answer (score 0):

When building such econometrics model, you want to grab as much historical data as you can.  That's so you can observe the relationship between your dependent variable and the macroeconomic ones for a long enough period that you have enough data points so that such relationships are somewhat reliable.  The observed correlations and regression coefficients will both be more statistically significant and meaningful than otherwise.

You want to observe those relationships over full economic cycles not just during a crisis.  Every crisis or downturn is somewhat different.  And, that is especially true of the 2008-2009 financial crisis.  If you focus solely on this period, the variables relationships were probably unstable and not so representative of any other economic environment except for one identical to 2008-2009 which may not happen for another 80 years or so (the most recent parallel is really the Great Depression that started in 1929).

When looking at stress test scenarios.  They go out several years (2014, 2015, 2016, etc...).  As structured, the first year or two they do reflect a severe and protracted downturn.  But, sometimes by the second half of the second year and onword... they actually reflect a recovery.  The latter can be structured as a slow one or sometimes even a really strong one.  If within your model you have only the 2008-2009 as a learning history, the model will have no idea on how to estimate sales during a recovery or a more normal economic climate.  In other words, your standard economic climate could become "out of sample" since you have never captured such a climate in your 2008-2009 learning history.  For an econometrics model... this spells disaster.  In this specific situation, I would definitely grab the entire data set from 2001 to the present.  As is, this data set is actually quite short to develop a reliable econometrics model.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more precise goal of the analysis needs to be articulated. If the objective is to come up with revenue projections in worst case scenario *only*, then I think it is appropriate to only use data from recession periods.

If you are mixing in data from other non-recession years, you are liable to get more optimistic results and not answer your original question of what revenues are going to be like in recessions.

Ideally of course you want as much data as possible to draw inference, but it's not proper to add irrelevant data just because it's a hassle to use small sample statistical methods.

I think it is inappropriate to consider 7 years of data like the Basel Committee recommends For one thing, these people are not banks. Second of all, reserve requirements and people's demands for loans likely aren't comparable with people's demand for whatever product the questioner's companies are selling.

Comment: I disagree for the reasons outlined in my answer on October 5th and Kochede's answer on December 23d.  To study variable relationships, you have to look at complete economic cycle and as much data as you can get, not cherry pick only recessionary periods (they are all quite different).

Comment: True, except the questioner isn't really studying variable relationships. 

The goal is to determine revenues in worst case scenario only - not to find the general relationship between economic indicators and revenues.

Answer (score 0):

24 points (2 years) is too small data to get a reliable model in my experience with this exercise.

But even if you would have a 5 years of stress data - your probably still don't want to use only stress period to fit a model. Because your scenarios' pack contain *both* stressed and normal scenarios and even stressed one have some recovery part in the end.

So I would fit a model using all historical data - 2007/2008-crisis and normal periods; in this way the model will fit both stressed/normal dynamics and then your *future scenarios* - stress and baseline - is what will drive forecasts and what differentiate stress/normal forecasts rather than historical fitting data.

Comment: I agree with you on all counts.  But, unless I missed something you don't add anything to what I already stated on October 5th.

Comment: @GaetanLion Sorry, didn't have time to read all replies - only the question. I just shared my particular experience with building these stress scenarios forecasting models. Consider it as an extra evidence for your point of view.

Comment: @GaetanLion my main point is - stress _future scenarios_ is what gives you "stress" forecasts, you don't need to use "stress" historical data for this.